# How to do a mod rewrite if URI contains a string and doesn't match a certain file type?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite, web-config

I have a folder (specifically wp-content from WordPress) that I would like to protect from people directly accessing it. For example, if you visit:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme
```

I would like you to get a 404 error message or be redirected elsewhere. Without protecting this directory, the server throws a 500 error. Right now, I have this .htaccess file in that folder and it works wonderfully:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js|ico|eot|svg|ttf|woff|json|pdf)$">
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Is there a way to do this with a mod_rewrite? I would like to essentially say:

- If not any of these file types and contains the string "wp-content" in the URI, redirect to 404 (or even the home page).

Note: The reason I want a Mod Rewrite method is because the people who will ultimately end up hosting this are using a Windows Environment and will be using a simple mod_rewrite converter for web.config (IIS).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /wp-content/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js|ico|eot|svg|ttf|woff|json|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

To redirect to the homepage, replace the last line with:

```
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R]
```